# Row and column average in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table `tblStock` with 3 columns:

```
PartCode (NVARCHAR (50))
StockQty (INT)
Location (NVARCHAR(50))
```

Some example data below:

[image]

I want to get the following output,

[image]

I have written the following query to get the above output, `Avg` value is not being returned properly:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblStock') IS NOT NULL /*Then it exists*/ 
    DROP TABLE #tblStock 

SELECT * 
INTO #tblStock
FROM
    (SELECT 'A' PartCode,  10 StockQty, 'WHs-A' Location
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'B',   22,  'WHs-A'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'A',   1,   'WHs-B'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'C',   20,  'WHs-A'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'D',   39,  'WHs-F'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'E',   3,   'WHs-D'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'F',   7,   'WHs-A'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'A',   9,   'WHs-C'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'D',   2,   'WHs-A'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'F',   54,  'WHs-E') TAB

SELECT * FROM #tblStock 

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + Location + ']', '[' + Location + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM #tblStock) PV 
               ORDER BY Location 
-- Since we need Total in last column, we append it at last
SELECT @cols += ',[AVG]'

-- Variable to replace NULL with zero
DECLARE @NulltoZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+Location+'],0) AS ['+Location+']' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM #tblStock)TAB  
ORDER BY Location FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000) 
SELECT @NullToZeroCols += ',ISNULL([AVG],0) AS [AVG]'


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT PartCode,' + @NulltoZeroCols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT 
                 ISNULL(CAST(PartCode AS VARCHAR(30)),''AVG'')PartCode, 
                 AVG(StockQty) StockQty  , 
                 ISNULL(Location,''AVG'')Location              
                 FROM #tblStock
                 GROUP BY Location,PartCode
                 WITH CUBE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 AVG(StockQty)
                 FOR Location IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (PartCode=''AVG'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,PartCode' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Can anyone know the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obtain your desired result changing your SET query with this.
I think you need to add the RIGHT JOIN to list every PartCode and Location (else AVG function could not count correctly the number of items). I added ISNULL to AVG(StockQty) too.
Moreover you should cast average as numeric.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT PartCode,' + @NulltoZeroCols + ' FROM 
             (SELECT                    
                 ISNULL(CAST(X.PC AS VARCHAR(30)),''AVG'') PartCode, 
                 AVG(CAST(ISNULL(StockQty,0) AS NUMERIC(10,2))) StockQty,                  
                 ISNULL(Y.LC,''AVG'') Location              
                 FROM #tblStock
                 RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PartCode AS PC FROM #tblStock)  X
                          CROSS JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT Location AS LC FROM #tblStock) Y
                  ON Y.LC = #tblStock.LOCATION AND X.PC=#tblStock.PARTCODE
                 GROUP BY  Y.LC, X.PC  
                 WITH CUBE                 
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 AVG(StockQty)
                 FOR Location IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN (PartCode=''AVG'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,PartCode'
```

Output:

```
PartCode                       WHs-A                                   WHs-B                                   WHs-C                                   WHs-D                                   WHs-E                                   WHs-F                                   AVG
------------------------------ --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
A                              10.000000                               1.000000                                9.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                3.333333
B                              22.000000                               0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                3.666666
C                              20.000000                               0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                3.333333
D                              2.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                39.000000                               6.833333
E                              0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                3.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.500000
F                              7.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                0.000000                                54.000000                               0.000000                                10.166666
AVG                            10.166666                               0.166666                                1.500000                                0.500000                                9.000000                                6.500000                                4.638888
```